# Where is the "purge-journal-archiving" setting?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I am trying to setup incremental backups with journal archiving in MarkLogic, but I am having a hard time finding the setting "purge-journal-archiving" in the admin interface. In order to setup this up "purge-journal-archiving" needs to be set to "true". I have checked in the database's configure page and there is nothing to specify this while setting up the backup. I don't know if im missing something somewhere. Do I need to call it via the Rest API?

The documentation for this does not provide clear direction on where to change this.

## [Incremental Backup with Journal Archiving](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/backup_restore#id_70233)

> Incremental backup improves restore both time and space requirements over journal archiving, but it's not an either/or decision. You can, and should, use both where appropriate. If your goal is to be able to restore to any arbitrary point in time, while minimizing potential data loss, we suggest the following:
>
> 1. Configure a scheduled full backup at some coarse granularity (for example, weekly) and enable journal archiving
> 2. Configure a scheduled incremental backup as some finer granularity (for example, hourly), and specify `purge-journal-archiving=true`.
> 3. Set retain until backup on the database Merge Policy so that deleted fragments are retained until they have been included in an incremental backup. See Setting Merge Policy or `admin:database-set-retain-until-backup` for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find the purge journal archiving setting in the UI. I would think it would be on the Scheduled Backups page once you've selected a database, but could not find it there.

There are a few other ways you change this setting.

- When creating a incremental-backup through the xquery admin API you can set the purge-journal-archive flag. see for more detail (https://docs.marklogic.com/admin:database-daily-incremental-backup).
- You can also do it as part of HTTP request to the Management API. See for more details (https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/POST/manage/v2/databases). If you have a [ml-gradle](https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle) project, highly recommended this, you should be able to add this to your database settings file.
- You can also manually purge the journals after doing a backup or put it as part of script using the server JavaScript code (or [XQuery](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:database-journal-archive-purge)).  (https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp.databaseJournalArchivePurge). You could make this part of a main module or rest extension and call it. If you are really in a pinch you could call the [eval](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/POST/v1/eval) endpoint with the server side code.